# Pycharm 2017.2.4 always runs Querying skeleton update in background

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

Whenever I restart `pycharm` it starts with `Querying skeleton update` process in the background even when I have not changed/modified or updated any of my python libraries. I am using Anaconda 5.0 as my default and only python version installed on the system.

Due to this process it takes too long for `pycharm` to respond initially after launching the application.

Is there any setting to not run this update when there are no changes made to the python library or will I have to disable it.

Are there any settings or changes that I am missing?

I also have attached the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bO93NKVJDJIUbElwAyLKdUMfxaM-jSwl/view?usp=sharing) generated.

**EDIT:**

Issue is still same with the `2017.3.1`, `2018` version of Pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

From the log I wonder if the problem is not related to permissions with which you run PyCharm vs. the ones you installed it with.

> Not found pregenerated skeletons at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2017.2.3\skeletons\skeletons-win-401-python-3.6.2.zip

I do not have this problem and the file above exists in my install of PyCharm (version `PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1`) installed at roughly the same location has the file in: `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.1\skeletons\skeletons-win-401-python-3.6.2.zip`

In your case PyCharm attempted to read the collected skeletons from your profile folder and it seems it failed and continued regenerating them:

> 2017-09-30 20:30:59,302 [ 282598]   INFO -
>   ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Binary skeletons directory for SDK
>   Python 3.6.2 (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe)
>   (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe)):
>   C:/Users/sjain/.PyCharm2017.2/system/python_stubs/-313451744
>
> 2017-09-30 20:30:59,318 [ 282614]   INFO -
>   ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - User skeletons directory for SDK
>   Python 3.6.2 (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe)
>   (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe)): C:/Program
>   Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2017.2.3/helpers/python-skeletons

Please attempt to run as `Administrator` to see if the behaviour is different. If it is then it is likely related to permissions.

[The issue has been known for a while](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205806059-How-can-I-disable-skeletons-update-) (since 2011) but no solution was offered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I always start it with administrator access, I understand it was unable to find that file, but after cashing it next time when I restart pycharm it should not have the same issue but It still runs the skeleton update in background.

Comment: Then maybe that's the problem? Have you tried running with standard user credentials? Is the behaviour the same?

Comment: it always by default launches in administrator mode, I am not sure how to launch it in non administrator mode, will still try to launch it and see, Thanks for the update

Answer (score -1):

to any one having this problem :

disable antivirus and run it administrator mode and it's solved , i tired million thing and this is the only thing worked for me .
my version 2022.1.2 and good luck everyone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).